# Echarts graph zoom

Tags: javascript, graph, zooming, echarts

I am using lib echarts and I would like to zoom automatically to one of nodes on page load. Cant find any option/action to do that with type graph and I dont know any other javascript hack to do that.

Here is link 
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=graph-simple

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Check out the datazoom in their api: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#action.dataZoom

I haven't used that function myself, but it sounds like what you are looking for.